# Replace strings many to many in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, char, character

I have a problem related String.Replace method. Firstly I try to change many strings as alphabets, for example,

```
article = article.Replace('b', 'd').Replace('B', 'D');
article= article.Replace('d', 'g').Replace('D', 'G');
```

char of 'b' or 'B' changes 'g' or 'G', not 'd' or 'D' as I expected. Is there any other options to solve this obstacle?
Thanks..

Comment: What is the problem ? `article = article.Replace('b', 'd').Replace('B', 'D');` this doesn't change b,B to d,D ?

Comment: no, b or B changes as g or G, cause of second line.

Comment: The second line override the first line!

Comment: -1: you are explicitly changing `b -> d -> g` - not sure what else you expect.

Comment: Friend, you replace overridden string again and result your "d,D" are replaced with g,G

Comment: I don't expect that, I wonder if there is any other options for this problem like **many to many** replace process..

Comment: To make the question better please add your goal or completely describe how you want actual replacement to work. I.e. maybe you want to replace each character with another one?

Comment: Smells like homework...

Answer (score 5):

If you are saying that **b**'s end up as **g**'s, then this is because you are:

1. Changing **b**'s to **d**'s,  then,
2. Changing those **d**'s, (as well as original **d**'s), to **g**'s

If you are trying to change the characters that are **b** to **d**, and *then* change **only** those characters that were **d**'s before step 1 into **g**'s, ...
  ...  then do the steps in the opposite order.

1. Changing **d**'s to **g**'s,  then,
2. Changing those **b**'s to **d**'s

Answer (score 0):

This is an often recurring task. I suggest creating an extension method. Place it in a static class.  Its namespace must be "visible" where you are using the extension method.

```
public static string TranslateChars(this string s, string originalChars,
                                                   string replacementChars)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) {
        return s;
    }
    if (originalChars == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(originalChars);
    }
    if (replacementChars == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(replacementChars);
    }
    if (originalChars.Length != replacementChars.Length) {
        throw new ArgumentException(
                   "'originalChars' and 'replacementChars' must have same length.");
    }

    // Fill translation dictionary
    var translations = new Dictionary<char, char>(originalChars.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < originalChars.Length; i++) {
        translations.Add(originalChars[i], replacementChars[i]);
    }

    //Translate
    var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++) {
        char replacement;
        if (translations.TryGetValue(sb[i], out replacement)) {
            sb[i] = replacement;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Applied to your problem:

```
article = article.TranslateChars("bBdD","dDgG");
```

---

Note: The `StringBuilder` allows you to replace single characters within a text, which you cannot do directly with a `string`, since strings are immutable.

Also since we do all the translations in a single pass, we avoid the problem that you encountered, namely that a character translated already is inadvertently translated a second time.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, you're doing the `B -> D` replacement first, followed by the `D -> G` replacement. So what you're really doing is `B -> G` and `D -> G`.

A declarative way to avoid this problem of choosing the correct ordering of replacements is as follows.

```
var map = new Dictionary<char, char>
{
    { 'b', 'd' },
    { 'B', 'D' },
    { 'd', 'g' },
    { 'D', 'G' }
};

article = new string(article
    .Select(x => map.ContainsKey(x) ? map[x] : x)
    .ToArray());
```